# What's the C# equivalent of Java's "for (String currLine: allLines)"?

Tags: c#, java, for-loop, equivalent

I've got some Java code along the lines of:

```
Vector<String> allLines = new Vector<String>();
allLines.add("line 1");
allLines.add("line 2");
allLines.add("line 3");
for (String currLine: allLines) { ... }
```

Basically, it reads a big file into a lines vector then processes it one at a time (I bring it all in to memory since I'm doing a multi-pass compiler).

What's the equivalent way of doing this with C#? I'm assuming here I won't need to revert to using an index variable.

---

Actually, to clarify, I'm asking for the equivalent of the whole code block above, not *just* the `for` loop.

Comment: I thought `for(String currLine: allLines)` was the equivalent for c#'s  foreach :-)

Comment: This question is [a joke](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/39/c?userid=14860), right?

Comment: No, @quantum, unfortunately not :-) While I've done some WPF stuff, I'm no Jon Skeet, and this is actually the first time I've had to convert code of the foreach kind. 400 upvotes for C# questions must be due to some sort of C/C++/Java tag crossover.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List<string>` can be accessed by index and resizes automatically like Vector.

So:

```
List<string> allLines = new List<string>();
allLines.Add("line 1");
allLines.Add("line 2");
allLines.Add("line 3");
foreach (string currLine in allLines) { ... }
```

Answer (score 6):

That would be the `foreach` construct.  Basically it is capable to extract an `IEnumerable` from the supplied argument, and will store all of it's values into the supplied variable.

```
foreach( var curLine in allLines ) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's

```
foreach (string currLine in allLines)
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`foreach(string currLine in allLines) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<string> allLines = new List<string>
{
    "line 1",
    "line 2",
    "line 3",
};
foreach (string currLine in allLines) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Vector is just a simple list, so this would be the c# equivalent

```
List<string> allLines = new List<string>();
allLines.add("line 1");
allLines.add("line 2");
allLines.add("line 3");
foreach (string currLine in allLines) { ... }
```